# Investigating the function $f(x,y)=2xy-|x|-y$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

> Find the local and global min/max points of $f(x,y)=2xy-|x|-y$. 
> Does the function has a global max/min point in the plane?

For the first question, I splitted it to when $x\ge0$ and when $x<0$. 
for $x\ge0$:  $f(x,y)=2xy-x-y. $
$f_x=2y-1$, $f_y=2y-1 \Longrightarrow(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. 
$f_{xx}*f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2=-4$ which means this is a "Saddle" point. 
When $x < 0$: $f(x,y)=2xy+x-y$
$f_x=2y+1$ 
$f_y=2x-1$ 
So I got $(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})$ which is outside the area $x<0$. 

Question: Do I need to check $x=0$ seperately? I think not because when $x=0$ the absolute value doesn't matter anymore. (but not sure). 
For the second question, I know that the plane isn't a bounded area. But I'm not sure why is it the plane they're asking about and not the space, so if it's the plane, that means I could just set $f(x,y)=0$? I'm not sure how to solve this question. 
Any help or feedback is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If $x \geq 0$ for example, $f(x,y)= 2 (xy- \frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}) = 2 (x - \frac{1}{2})(y-\frac{1}{2}) - \frac{1}{2}$. Can you check what you wrote for $x \lt 0$? It is not correct. On your second question, I am not sure which plane it is referring to.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for the comment, tbh I'm not sure what you mean about when $x<0$, could you please explain?

Comment: how do you get point $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$? Is that just a typo?

Comment: @MathLover Oh yes the minus should be on the y, ill fix

Comment: I think it is the $(x,y)$ plane, and asking is there a point $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)$ is globally maximum or minimum.

Comment: Why do you want to set $f(x,y)=0$?

Comment: You should check $x=0$ separately since $f$ is not differentiable there and local extrema can occur where the function is not differentiable.

Comment: @md2perpe it was a misunderstanding on my part, I thought that in the plane means in the xy plane, but now I guess it just asks if $f$ has any global extremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local extremum can occur at three types of points:

1. boundary points,
2. internal points where the function is not differentiable,
3. internal points where the gradient vanishes.

If $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then there are no boundary points.

The function is not differentiable when $x=0$ because of the $|x|$ term. When $x=0$ you have $f(x,y) = f(0,y) = -y$ which has no local extremum and also takes all values in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $f$ has no local extremum on the $y$ axis ($x=0$) and neither a global minimum nor a global maximum.

For $x>0$ you have $f(x,y)=2xy-x-y$ so $\nabla f = (2y-1, 2x-1),$ which vanishes at $(x,y)=(\frac12, \frac12).$ Setting $x=\frac12+h$ and $y=\frac12+k$ gives
$$
f = 2(\frac12+h)(\frac12+k)-(\frac12+h)-(\frac12+k) = -\frac12+2hk
$$
which takes values both above and below $f(\frac12,\frac12)=-\frac12$ (even for small $h,k$) so this is a saddle point.

For $x<0$ you have $f(x,y)=2xy+x-y$ so $\nabla f = (2y+1, 2x-1),$ which vanishes at $(x,y)=(\frac12, -\frac12).$ This however breaks against the condition $x<0$ and we can conclude that there is no local extremum for $x<0$.

Thus, $f$ has one saddle point at $(x,y)=(\frac12,\frac12)$ and neither any local nor global extremum of any type.

Comment: Thanks alot for the organized and well explained answer, but something that's bothering me is you took $(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})$, which is found at $x<0$, but it's outside that space, is it a mistake or it should be considered and im missing stuff? another question is how do you proof that $f$ doesn't have no global max/min? is the fact that $f$ is differentiable and it didn't have any local min/max points lead to not having global extremum? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @Pwaol. You're right, I made a mistake when not noticing that $(\frac12, -\frac12)$ was outside of $x<0$. I have corrected that now.

Comment: @Pwaol. When $x=0$ you have $f=-y$ which takes all values in $\mathbb{R},$ i.e. $f$ has no minimal value nor a maximal value. Therefore $f$ has no global extrema.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this, if $x=0$, then aren't we looking at $xz$ plane? why is that enough to show $f$ doesn't have a global extremum? (I can understand it in 2d but 3d is confusing me)

Comment: @Pwaol. You haven't specified the domain of $f$ but without a given domain, $f$ is assumed to be defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ since there are 2 variables. Thus we can not talk about its values for different $z$.

Comment: Oh now it makes more sense! so we know that $f$ can take all values in $\mathbb{R}$, why is that enough to say that it doesn't have an extremum? (I'm trying to link to normal one variable function where I took limits of y to infinity or minus infinity and showed that the function goes to infinity or minus infinity which means there's no global extremum, but here it's one more variable, so shouldn't there be more work to do than set $x=0$ and show that $f$ goes to infinity on $x=0$?)

Comment: A maximum is a value $R<\infty$ such that $f(x,y)\leq R$ for all $(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)=R$ for some $(x,y)$. Therefore $f$ must be bounded from above. Analogously, for a minimum to exist the function must be bounded from below. It's exactly like in the 1D case.

Comment: I see what you mean now!! it's enough that only on $y=-x$ the function isn't bounded for us to show that a global extremum doesn't exist. I really appreciate the help, Thanks alot!