# Find Global max/min of $f(x,y) = 2xy-x-y$ in $D$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

> Find Global max/min of $f(x,y) = 2xy-x-y$ in $D$. 
> $D=\{(x,y)| x^2+y^2\le1, y\ge-x \}$

What I did: 
I drew $D$ first, and now my plan is to find inner critical points, then find max/min points on each of part of the circle and the line, then find the value of the intersections of the circle and the line. And according to all this I decide global max/min. 
(According to weierstrass theorem, $D$ is bounded and closed, which means $f$ has max and min in $D$).

1. Critical inner points:

   $\nabla f=(2y-1,2x-1)=0 \Longrightarrow (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.
2. On the line: $y=-x$ 
   $f(x,-x)=-2x^2 \Longrightarrow f'=-4x=0 \Longrightarrow x=0,y=0 \Longrightarrow(0,0)$. 
   On the circle (And here comes the problems: 
   First I tried to do with lagrange multipliers with $\nabla L = (2y-1-2x\lambda, 2x-1-2y\lambda)=0$ and $x^2+y^2=1$. 
   But things got Really complicated and I couldn't find the points. 
   So I decided to parametrize the circle $\vec r(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ and $f(r(t))=\sin(2t)-\cos(t)-\sin(t)$ 
   $f'=2\cos(2t)+\sin(t)-\cos(t)=0$ But I also got stuck here calculating this.. 
   Last thing I tried is $y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$, and you know what happened too. 

   I would really appreciate any help with how to solve these stuff. 
   Thanks in advance!

Comment: One the unit circle, we have $f(x,y)=2xy-x-y=(x+y)^2 -x^2-y^2 -x-y=(x+y)^2-(x+y)-1$. That expression can now be examined using $1$-dimensional analysis. You just need to examine what values $x+y$ can take.

Comment: A very similar question was asked today https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4190749/399263, is it related ?

Comment: @Ingix Thanks for the help!!, could you please emphasize on how did you think of the trick? that's a really specific and smart trick to see, is there any signs which made you think to try it this way? would love to hear how what led you to try it.

Comment: @zwim It's related with the function (but that one has absolute value), but it's a completely different problem with a different solution, there wasn't a closed and bounded region in the one you mentioned (I asked that question too).

Comment: @Pwaol I guess when you have a restriction expressed by an equation, you want to "substitute it" into the function you want to optimize to get rid of one variable. As you noted, that isn't straigthforward. Since the restriction contains the term $x^2+y^2$, and there is a $2xy$ term in $f$, it seemed natural to try to see if combining them to $x^2+y^2+2xy=(x+y)^2$ leads to something, which it luckily did in this case.

Comment: @Pwaol. Seeing $2xy$ can make you think about $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$. And in this case you are lucky since $x^2+y^2$ is constant on the semicircular part of the boundary. And then $-x-y=-(x+y)$ so you really can write $f(x,y)$ in terms of $x+y$ on the semicircle.

Comment: @Pwaol If you express it as $(x+y)^2 - (x+y) - (x^2+y^2)$, that works for minimum but you need to show that the minimum occurs at the boundary $x^2+y^2 = 1$ which is easy. But note that the maximum does not occur at the boundary $x^2+y^2 = 1$, rather at the boundary $y = -x$ and at $(0, 0)$. For that, you need additional work.

Comment: @MathLover I'm incredibly sorry, I've missed your answer and just noticed it. I will take my time understanding it now.

Comment: @MathLover Oh I wish I could help you with that, but I didn't really read any books about this, I just use the materials I've learnt in the lectures. (Btw your answer is really nice but it's much high level for myself to be able to deal with that trigonometric function, I would've been stuck from the start :(. But thanks alot I will just try read it a couple of times to get the idea, But I'm not getting at the start where you said $r^2 \le r$, how did you reach that?

Comment: As $r \in (0,1), r^2 \leq r$. It is not that difficult to deal with the analysis. Feel free to go through and then ask whatever questions. I promise you will get it :)

Comment: @MathLover I would appreciate it if you could take a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190627/prove-or-disprove-this-function-has-directional-derivative-in-every-direction-a , It got two answers, and they both prove that the directional derivative exists at every direction, but the final answer was False. It's still bugging me and would appreciate if you could approve / disapprove the answers or the final answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, convert it into polar coordinates.

$f(r, \theta) = r^2 \sin 2\theta - r \sin\theta - r\cos\theta$
$(0 \leq r \leq 1, - \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4})$

First for maximum,

We observe that at $r = 0, f(r,\theta) = 0$. So we try to find a point in the given interval where function is positive.

We have $r^2 \leq r$ and $\sin \theta + \cos\theta = \sqrt2 \sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta)$ which is positive for $- \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$. So we must have $\sin (2\theta) \gt \sqrt2 \sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta)$.

For $\theta$ in first quadrant, $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. So we do not have a solution. For $\theta \in (-\frac{\pi}{4},0] \cup [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{4}), \sin 2\theta$ is negative and so we again do not have a solution.

That leads to maximum of $0$.

Now for minimum,

$f(r, \theta) = r^2 \sin 2\theta - r \sin\theta - r\cos\theta$

$ = r^2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta) - r \sqrt2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta)$

Writing $(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4})$ as $t$,

$ = r^2 \cos (2t) - r \sqrt2 \cos t = 2(r^2\cos^2t - \frac{r \cos t}{\sqrt2} - \frac{r^2}{2})$

$ = 2 [(r\cos t - \frac{1}{2\sqrt2})^2 - \frac{1}{8} - \frac{r^2}{2}]$ ...$(i)$

So the minimum occurs when $r$ is max (which is $1$) and $\cos (\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$

That leads to minimum of $ - \frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: You may want to check the graph too - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/co65timri0